# Apache2 404 error while accessing a file that is physically located in the directory on server

Tags: php, apache, apache2

On my ubuntu server i have user farmer inside home/farmer i created directories /**var/www/bit**/ inside it i put file index.html

I have granted following rights to directories and index.html file

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  1 08:46 var 
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  1 08:46 www
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  1 08:48 bit
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 188 Mar  1 08:48 index.html
```

I installed Apache2 and in directory /etc/apache2/sites-available created config file bit.conf with following instructions

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                        
   ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com                     
   DocumentRoot /var/www/bit                             
   ServerName 64.227.17.11
   ServerAlias www.64.227.17.11

<Directory /var/www/bit>                                  
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog 
   ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog 
   ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I run command `sudo a2ensite bitr.conf`
Than command `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

And want to access my index.html through curl when i run `curl http://64.227.17.11/index.html` but it's return 404 not found error but when i run `curl http://64.227.17.11/` i see sratus 200 what can be a problem that apache don't find index.html file in my logs for request which give 404 the following output. In access.log

```
64.227.17.11 - - [01/Mar/2024:11:39:44 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 435 "-" "curl/7.88.1"
```

For curl http://64.227.17.11/ in access.log `69.164.217.245 - - [01/Mar/2024:11:20:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 530 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"`

In /var/log/apache2/error.log output is following `[Fri Mar 01 11:39:32.709878 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2427243] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully                                           [Fri Mar 01 11:39:32.885861 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2427553] AH00163: Apache/2.4.55 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations                     [Fri Mar 01 11:39:32.885970 2024] [core:notice] [pid 2427553] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'`

What is a problem which cause 404 error ?